# var A == var B == 1 looking for truthy. Not working. Is it possible?

Tags: javascript

Not sure this is doable, but I am looking for a truth return if, for example..
var A = 100;
var B = 100;

```
(A == B == 100)
```

I figured this would return true. Because A == B (they are both 100) and as such, they both equal 100.

But it is always false.

EDIT::: Thanks, Yeah - I appreciate the repsonses.. I was hoping there was some nifty shorhand than doing (A === 100 ) && ( B === 100) etc... But thank all very much.

Comment: slightly shorter:
    (A==B) && (A==100)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either it evaluates as

```
(A == B) == 100
```

or as

```
A == (B == 100)
```

In both cases you compare a boolean with 100. This is of course always false. You want

```
(A==100) && (B==100)
```

To see what is going on you might want to run [the Example below as JSFiddle:](http://jsfiddle.net/PKh7c/5/)

```
var A = 100;
var B = 100;

alert("B == 100: " + (B == 100));
alert("A == (B == 100):" + (A == (B == 100)));
alert("A == B:" + (A == B));
alert("(A == B) == 100:" + ((A == B) == 100));
alert("A == B == 100):" + (A == B == 100));
alert("(A == 100) && (B == 100):" + ((A == 100) && (B == 100)));
```

Answer (score 2):

```
A== 100 && B == 100
```

Is what you are looking for.

Answer (score 2):

It translates to `true===100` which is obviously `false`. You can use `a===b && b===100`

Answer (score 1):

Because the after the second expression that is `(B == 100)` the value of `A` it gets compared to `boolean` so it would always be `false`

that is:

```
A == (B == 100)
```

Which becomes

```
A == true
```

Which evaluated to `false`

So the correct version should be:

```
(A == 100) && (B == 100)
```

### [Live demo](http://jsfiddle.net/hZAat/1/)

Answer (score 0):

i think it can be interpreted as

```
(A == B) && ((A == B) == 100)
```

obviously,it's not true

Comment: `(A == B) == 100` .... how can ever a boolean `==` to Number ? How does this answers the Q ?